# Excel VBA - Combining import and export macros

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I have two separate macros called ImportData and ExportData.
ExportData sends data to a sheet called Temp. It later gets sent to a .csv file. All of that is working fine.
ex:

```
    Sheets("Orders").Range("A1:C6").Copy
    Sheets("Temp").Range("A55:C60").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

ImportData does the opposite of ExportData:
ex:

```
    Sheets("Temp").Range("A55:C60").Copy
    Sheets("Orders").Range("A1:C6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Is there a way to do this with one macro, instead of having two that are basically the same, except that copy and paste are flip flopped?

Each macro has hundreds of lines of copy and paste similar to above, not just the 2 lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a table of "from" and "to" addresses on a worksheet (can be hidden if necessary) then you can use something like this and it's going to be more manageable:

```
Sub Tester()

    CopyIt       ' defaults to Import
    CopyIt False ' specify Export

End Sub

Sub CopyIt(Optional DoImport As Boolean = True)
    Dim rw As Range, r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    For Each rw In Sheet1.Range("A1:B50").Rows
        Set r1 = Sheets("Temp").Range(rw(1).Value)
        Set r2 = Sheets("Orders").Range(rw(2).Value)
    Next rw

    If DoImport Then
        r2.Value = r1.Value
    Else
        r1.Value = r2.Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub PasteFromTo(FromRange As Excel.Range, ToRange As Excel.Range)
FromRange.Copy
ToRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Call it like:

```
Sub test()
PasteFromTo Sheets("Temp").Range("A55:C60"), Sheets("Orders").Range("A1:C6")
End Sub
```